# How to create a recyclerview wirth different design on first cell

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

Is there any way to create a recycler where its first cell is twice as big as the other cells and all the other cells are in between the top and bottom of the first cell. Here is a drawing example because I can not explain it properly with words.

[image]

Comment: See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type

Comment: see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37006115/android-recyclerview-with-gridlayoutmanager-make-item-span-multiple-rows

Answer (score 0):

Create a POJO class for each different view types and pass the values to the POJO classes and add the POJO as the recycler view item.You can insert and render multiple view types inside a recycler view .