# Recyclerview item custom span

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I'm implementing an image selection screen that looks like the below image

[image: Image Selection Screen]

I want to use recyclerview to implement this but don't know how to do it.

Help me to figure out it.
Thanks in advance!!

[Edit]: number of items is not fixed.

Comment: If number of items fixed then you do not need a `RecyclerView` for this it will be easy just to create a layout like this ..

Comment: Actually, the first item would be shown as large and the other all will be small ones and currently, I have implemented the way you are telling. And the number of items is not fixed.

Comment: it's may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37006115/android-recyclerview-with-gridlayoutmanager-make-item-span-multiple-rows

Comment: You said the number of items is not fixed, could you show some examples of what it should look like with more or less items? That might give people a good indication of what solution to aid with

Comment: The first item will show a span of 2*2 and the other will be normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I got a library named [SpannedGridLayoutManager](https://github.com/jmartinesp/SpannedGridLayoutManager) that fulfills my requirement.